# Logstash is not able to find logstash.conf file

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana

I am trying to manage log using ELK in a Spring Boot project on Windows System.
Project hierarchy is given blow.

[image]

Code in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.20.4'
services:
  Elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      discovery.type: single-node    
    ports:
    - '9200:9200'
    - '9300:9300'
    networks:
      - elk

  Logstash:
    image: logstash:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/dc-demo-main/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
    - ./logstash/pipeline:/dc-demo-main/logstash/pipeline:ro
    command: logstash -f /dc-demo-main/logstash/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
      - Elasticsearch
    ports:
    - '9600:9600'
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"    
    networks:
      - elk

  Kibana:
    image: kibana:7.16.2
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always       
    ports:
    - '5601:5601'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200  
    depends_on:
      - Elasticsearch  
    networks:
      - elk
volumes:
  elastic_data: {}

networks:
  elk:
```

logstash.conf

```
input{
    file{
        path => "C:/ELK_Logs/elk-stack.log"
                start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

output{
    stdout{
           codec=>rubydebug
        }
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    }
}
```

logstash.yml

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /dc-demo-main/logstash/pipeline
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "localhost:9200" ]
```

On Elastic Search dashboard log is not getting populated
When trying to create index in logstash.conf file index is also not getting created. when I am trying o search under http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official documents:

[Directory Layout for Docker Images](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.16/dir-layout.html)

So default path for conf file will be: **/usr/share/logstash/pipeline**
But your command is looking for it under **/dc-demo-main/logstash/logstash.conf**

I think this is worth to give it a try.

Here is a similar example: [DOCKER - ELK 7.6 : ELASTIC STACK WITH DOCKER COMPOSE](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker_ELK_7_6_Elastic_Stack_Docker_Compose.php)